# Label the output value on Graph Plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I have a value in an array(KG) and I have to label the value on a Graph plotted using Plotly.
I have used the code line which is mentioned below:

```
CLE,Z,K,Rmv,SigS,M,N,SigD,SigG,M2,SigM,σ_amp_BauteilTAES,σ_amp_BauteilPES,KG,SigA1,SigN2M,kN2E6,SigA,slope,σamp10,σmean10,σamp100,σmean100,σamp1000,σmean1000,σamp10000,σmean10000,σamp100000,σmean100000 = Mittelspannung()

df['SigA1'] = SigA1
df['SigM'] = SigM
df['SigN2M'] = SigN2M
df['kN2E6'] = kN2E6
df['SigA'] = SigA
df['slope'] = slope
print(df)
fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])
fig.update_xaxes(title_text="Mean Stress [MPa]")
fig.update_yaxes(title_text="Stress Amplitude [MPa]")
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=SigM, y=SigN2M, name="N = 2M"))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=SigM[1:29], y=SigA1[1:29], name="N = 1"))
fig.update_layout(height=800,title_text= KG)
fig.parallel_coordinates( labels={"R=": "KG" })
fig.show()
```

I have all the output data in a function and I have get KG value on graph.
I'm encountered with an error and I have mentioned it below.
ValueError:
Invalid value of type 'builtins.list' received for the 'text' property of layout.title
Received value: [-0.408]
The 'text' property is a string and must be specified as:
- A string
- A number that will be converted to a string
Could anyone help in this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @JohanC- I have mentioned the code that I used to plot the graph. I have to label the value of KG on my graph.

Comment: Using text mode on scatter plots, you can display text strings. `fig.add_trace(go.scatter(mode='text', x=SigM, y=SigN2M, text=SigN2M,...))`

Comment: Well, your code is missing test data and the necessary imports.

Comment: @r-beginners I have to display a variable value(KG) on the graph in the place of title label. Which is defined in the function Mittelspannung().

Comment: Do you have sample data and current output? I am limited in my advice as it stands.

Comment: @r-beginners The output value of the KG is [-0.408]. It changes respective with my input values. So, the user needs the values to be labelled on a graph. For that I need line of code to add the variable output to a label. In simple the variable output values should be labelled on a graph. Could you please help me in this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: String annotations can be added with `fig.add_annotation()`. Try the following example. `XG = -0.408;fig = go.Figure();fig.add_annotation(x=x,y=y,text="XG:{}".format(XG),showarrow=False,yshift=10);fig.show();`

Comment: @r-beginners Thank you so much, the above code is working.

Comment: I think it means that where it was a string, it contained a number. Why don't you try converting the numerical value to a string?

Comment: I did it, that you so much @r-beginners